# Show "loading..." message while message is executed by Django server

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, web-services

I've encountered a minor problem with Django, rendering and Javascript.

In my Django app, I want to show a message like "Loading, please wait", then after a method (SalesforceConnector) returns a result, use that result (success or fail) to render another message accordingly.

I've already understood that the main thing will be to use javascript with ajax or jquery, but how can i wait for the method result exactly ?

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from api.SalesforceConnector import SalesforceConnector

def api(request, *args, **kwargs):
    print("Called")

    print(request)

    ### Show "Loading, please wait.." Message here

    sessionId = request.GET["sessionId"]
    routePlanId = request.GET["routePlanId"]
    apiURL = request.GET["apiURL"]
    sfAction = request.GET["action"]

    print(sessionId)

    salesforceConnector = SalesforceConnector(sessionId, routePlanId, apiURL, sfAction)

    ### Show message according to the SalesforceConnector result
```

Comment: If you want to show the message on the webpage itself, this is really a question about javascript. You are asking how to show a loading message while an async request is in progress.

Comment: The language in the post does not look JavaScript at all... Are you sure you have problem with code shown (than tag appropriately) or something else?

Comment: The code is in python (Using Django framework)